# Gauge.js Almost Full Circle

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to mimic one of the demos on gauge.js' website without luck. I am trying to figure out how to create a gauge that is actually almost full circle. Half circle gauge won't work for what I need it for. Any ideas?

This is what I have at the moment but it renders a half gauge.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    var opts = {
    lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
    angle: 0, // The length of each line
    lineWidth: 0.0001, // The line thickness
    pointer: {
    length: 0.9, // The radius of the inner circle
    strokeWidth: 0.035, // The rotation offset
    color: '#000' // Fill color
    },
    colorStart: '#FFF',   // Colors
    colorStop: '#FFF',    // just experiment with them
    strokeColor: '#E0E0E0',   // to see which ones work best for you
    generateGradient: true
    };
    var target = document.getElementById('foo'); // your canvas element
    var gauge = new Gauge(target);
    gauge.setOptions(opts); // create sexy gauge!
    gauge.maxValue = 3000; // set max gauge value
    gauge.animationSpeed = 32; // set animation speed (32 is default value)
    gauge.set(1250); // set actual value

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can draw a 360 degree guage indicator indicator using canvas context.rotate**

First declare your indicator styling:

```
    var indicatorX=150;
    var indicatorY=150;
    var indicatorBaseWidth=10;
    var indicatorHeight=75;
    var indicatorDegrees=0;
    var indicatorFill="maroon";
```

Then use this function to draw the indicator at any angle from 0 (vertical) to 360 (back to vertical):

Note the use of translate and rotate.

- Translate moves the context [0,0] drawing coordinate to the indicatorX/Y position
- Rotate will rotate the context to the currently specified degree of rotation

Also, notice context.save and context restore.

- Context.save() will save the state of the unmoved and unrotated canvas context.
- Context.restore() will restore the context state back to its unmoved and unrotated state.
- We use save/restore so that we don’t have to remember and adjust-for the previous rotation.

  ```
  function drawIndicator(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(indicatorX,indicatorY);
        ctx.rotate(indicatorDegrees*Math.PI/180);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(-indicatorBaseWidth/2,0);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(0,10,indicatorBaseWidth/2,0);
        ctx.lineTo(0,-indicatorHeight);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle="gray";
        ctx.lineWidth=3;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle=indicatorFill;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0,0,3,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle="gold";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
  }
  ```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/7BKDG/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <style>
      body{ background-color: ivory; }
      #wrapper{ position:relative; }
      canvas{ position:absolute; left:40px; top:5px; border:1px solid red;}
      #amount{ position:absolute; left:1px; top:5px; margin-bottom:15px; width:23px; border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; }
      #slider-vertical{ position:absolute; left:5px; top:40px; width:15px; height:225px; border:0px; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>

  $(function() {

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var indicatorX=150;
    var indicatorY=150;
    var indicatorBaseWidth=10;
    var indicatorHeight=75;
    var indicatorDegrees=0;
    var indicatorFill="maroon";


    $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 360,
      value: 0,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        indicatorDegrees=ui.value;
        drawIndicator();
      }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "value" ) );


    function drawIndicator(){
          ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
          ctx.save();
          ctx.translate(indicatorX,indicatorY);
          ctx.rotate(indicatorDegrees*Math.PI/180);
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(-indicatorBaseWidth/2,0);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(0,10,indicatorBaseWidth/2,0);
          ctx.lineTo(0,-indicatorHeight);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.strokeStyle="gray";
          ctx.lineWidth=3;
          ctx.stroke();
          ctx.fillStyle=indicatorFill;
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(0,0,3,0,Math.PI*2,false);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.fillStyle="gold";
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.restore();
    }


    drawIndicator();


  });   // end $(function(){});

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="amount" />
        <div id="slider-vertical"></div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is pretty awesome Mark. To work with what I am doing can you alter it to put the 0 at the bottom? Also, can you tell me which factor controls the 360 degree. What if I wanted to have it at 340 degree circle?

Comment: The  indicator angle is controlled by the indicatorDegrees variable.  To start the indicator at the bottom, just add +180 degrees when calculating the angle.  To limit the indicator to a maximum of 340, just disallow values > 340.  Here is an adjusted Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ywCvX/